# Proof using Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Use Fermat's Little Theorem to prove that

$11|(9n^{23}-5n^{13}+7n^3)$

Comment: we know that $n^{10} = 1 mod 11$ and now I'm trying to get what is $n^{23}$ and the other powers congruent to from  $n^{10}$

Comment: More hint: $n^{23}=n^{20}\cdot n^3=(n^{10})^2\cdot n^3$.

Comment: Also notice $n^{10}$ is congruent to $1$ mod $11$ iff $11$ does not divide $n$.  But if $11$ divides $n$ then the problem is even easier.

Comment: Ahh yes, I don't know how I didn't see it. 
$9n^{23}$ is congruent to $9n^3$ and so on for all the others.
Thanks Harald!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$n^{23}\equiv n^{13}\equiv n^3\pmod{11}$ so we get that
$$
9n^{23}-5n^{13}+7n^3\equiv11n^3\equiv0\pmod{11}
$$
Thus, $11|(9n^{23}-5n^{13}+7n^3)$.

Comment: @lhf: are you talking about $n^{20}\equiv n^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$? I fixed that immediately after posting. :-)

Comment: @lhf: Even for $n\equiv0$, Fermat's little theorem still gives $n^{23} =  (n^{11})^2\cdot n \equiv n^2\cdot n = n^3$.

Comment: ok, sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1):

If modular arithmetic is unfamiliar then one may use that $\rm\:11\mid \color{#C00}{n-n^{11}}\:$ by little Fermat, hence

$$\rm 11\mid7n^3\! - 5n^{13}\! + 9 n^{23}\, =\ (7n^2\! + 2n^{12}) (\color{#C00}{n-n^{11}}) + 11 n^{23}$$